# How to create template repo and push to children repos

Tags: git, github

I have a website template that I would like to use for several different sites. So I would like to create a template project and create *children* based on that template.

I have heard about [github template repositories](https://github.blog/2019-06-06-generate-new-repositories-with-repository-templates/). However, I'm not sure if I can continue development to the template repository and then push an update/merge to the children repos.

Is that possible?

Thanks.